Acumatica 'Web Service Endpoint' has been blocked by CORS policy whiling calling by JQuery ajax
I am using Acumatica 24R1 and using 'default' endpoint version '23.200.001' entity 'Customer' using Bearer token authentication using jQuery ajax method, getting error 'request has been blocked by CORS policy', Same I have tried with postman and MVC C# application it is working
with the following payload
grant_type:passwrd
scope:api
username:xx
Password:XX
Client_ID:xxxxxxx
client_secret:xxxxx
and

URL:{{AcumaticaInstance}}/identity/connect/token
Type:POST

get the Bearer token in response and pass the token in below GET request to get the data

URL:{{AcumaticaInstance}}/entity/default/23.200.001/Customer
Type:GET

When I tried this process with postman or MVC application using C#, above both API calling is working
When I tried this process whiling using jQuery ajax method getting error 'request been blocked by
CORS policy'
